# Form in dynamic table only applying to first version (Rails)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Hard to word this one, but essentially I have a collection of games. I have them outputting to a table, and I want a column for 'rating' - Which is your, personal, rating so it will be interactive.

I couldn't figure out the proper way to do this so I went with HTML/CSS - I used a 'form' so I could later submit it to the DB. All of this is my own band-aid so tell me if there is an easier way of doing it.

My issue now is ANY of the rating buttons I press, only work on the 1st row. I tried using ERB to make the form (Wondering if this has some magical change) as well as appending the 'index' of the `for_each` to the field, but no dice. In fact doing that makes it so the top-field can only be submitted one time and never again.

**The table generation**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">#</th>
            <th>Game Icon</th>
            <th>Game</th>
            <th>Playtime</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th class="text-right">Cost</th>
            <th class="text-right">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
    <% gamesList.each_slice(3) do |games| %>
        <% games.each_with_index do |game, index| %>

            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><%= index %></td>
                <td><%= game['name'] %></td>
                <td>
                     <% if game['img_icon_url'].blank? %>
                        <%= image_tag 'http://www.readyicons.com/IconSets/Sky_Light_(Basic)/32x32-no.png' %>
                      <% else %>
                        <%= image_tag "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/#{game['appid']}/#{game['img_icon_url']}.jpg" %>
                      <% end %>
                </td>
                <td><%= game['playtime_forever'] %></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="stars">
                      <form action="">
                        <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star<%=index%>"/>
                        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
                        <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
                        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
                        <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
                        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
                        <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
                        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
                        <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
                        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
                      </form>
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td class="text-right">$19.99(Static-TBD)</td>
                <td>Stuff</td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tr>

        <% end %>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I welcome any input, even if it completely changes how I'm doing it. (I don't know if Rails has a 'Fiddle' so I couldn't emulate this.)

(PS I'll be heavily using ratings on different controllers - If there is a gem or a better 'Rails Way' for this, I am definitely all ears.)

Answer (score 1):

some correction

- you have some miss matched tr and td inside loop games (fixed)
- to choose rating instead using radio, I suggest you use drop down selection (code included below)
- to edit multiple record directly within one form I think you can learn better from ryan bates technique ([railcast episode 165](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised?autoplay=true))

here is some correction and if you combined with ryan bates technique probably can help you achieve the purpose

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">#</th>
            <th>Game Icon</th>
            <th>Game</th>
            <th>Playtime</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th class="text-right">Cost</th>
            <th class="text-right">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% gamesList.each_slice(3) do |games| %>
            <% games.each_with_index do |game, index| %>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= index %></td>
                    <td><%= game['name'] %></td>
                    <td>
                         <% if game['img_icon_url'].blank? %>
                            <%= image_tag 'http://www.readyicons.com/IconSets/Sky_Light_(Basic)/32x32-no.png' %>
                          <% else %>
                            <%= image_tag "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/#{game['appid']}/#{game['img_icon_url']}.jpg" %>
                          <% end %>
                    </td>
                    <td><%= game['playtime_forever'] %></td>
                    <td>
                        <%= select_tag "index", "<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option> <option>5</option>".html_safe %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">$19.99(Static-TBD)</td>
                    <td>Stuff</td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and in case you needed later, I gave you some code to render stars based on index (I'm using bootstrap glyphicon) [bootstrap sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

```
<% if games.index %>
    <% (1..games.index).each do |i| %>
      <%= '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>'.html_safe %>    
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I'll watch the railscast to understand it better - I tried out your card but it provides a blank drop-down. I do see `<select name="index" id="index">[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]</select>` when I inspect it.

Comment: just edited , my previous code previously using form blog, I just edit using simple select_tag, if you later using form blog with form.select    tag then this will work <%= form.select :index, [1,2,3,4,5], include_blank: false  %>